# Redirect all incoming and outgoing traffic from a port to a specific ip

Tags: iptables, docker, iptables-redirect

I am running a node server inside a docker container on port `8080` and i can access it via `172.17.0.2:8080` (container ip) now i want to access this ip from `localhost:9099`.

I have tried using iptables to redirect this traffic coming at `localhost:9099` to `172.17.0.2:8080` but all measures are in vain.

This is the command i was using. Please correct me where i am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9099 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:8080
```

I took help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897743/exposing-a-port-on-a-live-docker-container) ans but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your attempt:

- using `localhost` means connections are initiated from the host, not routed from an other host. Thus it requires the `OUTPUT` chain, not the `PREROUTING` chain since routing was not initially involved.
- the source IP, which would be `127.0.0.1` has to be changed too once the destination is changed. This requires an additional `POSTROUTING` rule. An optional `-m conntrack --ctstate DNAT` match will check that the first `OUTPUT` did match first and it's not some spoofing attempt.
- At least on Linux `127.0.0.0/8` is handled specially in the routing stack, and the packet will be dropped before the `POSTROUTING` rule triggers. To remove the special handling and allow routing "outside" of the `127.0.0.0/8` block, the interface on which the redirection will happen must have the flag [`route_localnet`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.17#n1117) set to 1, or none of the above will be enough.

Since the interface is not known from the Question, the interface name is retrieved from the route and put in a variable. Adapt it if needed. You can also use the `all` pseudo-interface instead to set the [flag](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.17#n1117) globally.

So in the end this boils down to (as root or using `sudo`):

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9099 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:8080
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 172.17.0.2 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j MASQUERADE
interface=$(ip -o route get 172.17.0.2 | grep -o 'dev [^ ][^ ]*'|sed 's/^dev //')
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/$(interface)/route_localnet
```

Once all that is said, you should try using a non-`127.0.0.0/8` address, still local to the host. This could simplify things, not requiring `route_localnet` (and possibly sometimes not requiring the additional `POSTROUTING` rule).